# How to display the numbers of each rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problem to display the numbers of each rows. I am displaying a table with `LIMIT` of up to `20 rows`. I can display the numbers in the `while loop` but when user click for next rows it will display the number back to 1. How can I display it as a continue number example, `1-20, 21-40, etc`? Below are my codes:

```
<?php    
//SQL AND LIMIT codes here
$x = '1';
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $pr_id=$row['pr_id'];
?>
        <tr>
         <td align="center"><?php echo $x; //display the number ?></td> 
         <td><?php echo html_entity_decode($row['title']); ?></td>
         <td align="center"><?php echo date("d/m/y",strtotime($row['submit_date'])); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['purchase_type']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    $x++;
    } 
} 
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);

echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a>';
?>
```

Comment: which value you are passing as $next in anchor tag?? 1,2,3,4..like that?

Comment: yap , `$next` is the page number.

Comment: use data table or pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned $next is page number:

One solution is you can do:

```
$x = 1 + (($next -1 ) * 20);
```

So...
When `$next = 1 (first page) $x = 1 + (0*20) = 1`

When `$next = 2 (second page) $x = 1 + (1*20) = 21`

When `$next = 3 (third page) $x = 1 + (2*20) = 41`
So on...

Comment: **thanks** for the help! It works for me. Nice math. _Programming Connects People_

Answer (score 1):

Can you please use limit in your sql query and you use below code for getting limit.

```
$start = 1 + ((page number)*20);
$end = $start + 19;
```

Now you can set it in your sql query

```
$sql = "select * from  table name where limit".$start.", ".$end;
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<?php    
  if(isset($_REQUEST['pn'])){
     $pn = $_REQUEST['pn'];
  } else {
     $pn = '1';
  }
  $x = $pn * 20;  //place your no. of rows instead of 20
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $pr_id=$row['pr_id'];
?>
    <tr>
     <td align="center"><?php echo $x; //display the number ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo html_entity_decode($row['title']); ?></td>
     <td align="center"><?php echo date("d/m/y",strtotime($row['submit_date'])); ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['purchase_type']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
  $x++;
  } 
} 
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn);

echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a>';
?>
```